# Allowing some padding space in polar charts using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using [Highcharts.com](http://www.highcharts.com) to create a Spider chart. My data is normalised (each value in the series is in the range [0.0, 1.0]). It may happen that for a given polyline, some/all of the values are exactly 0.0: this makes part or all of the polyline to degenerate in a line or even a single dot. See the following a Minimal Working Example (I'd post a picture but I am not yet allowed to): I am referring to the `Degenerate Case` (the third line). I would like, for instance, to shift each axis so that it displays values in the range [-0.15, 1.0], so that even in the worst case I have a proper area. This would improve a lot the readability of the graph. After reading the online manual, I tried several combinations of `offset`, `padding`, etc. (with both min and max) that suggest to help somehow, but I had no success.

```
$(function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      polar: true,
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Budget vs spending',
      x: -80
    },
    pane: {
      size: '80%'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Development', 'Customer Support', 
        'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
      lineWidth: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
      gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
      lineWidth: 0,
      min: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: true,
      pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
    },
    legend: {
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 70,
      layout: 'vertical'
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Allocated Budget',
      data: [1.00, 0.40, 0.80, 0.50, 0.90, 0.20],
      pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
      name: 'Actual Spending',
      data: [0.00, 0.30, 0.00, 0.80, 0.90, 0.70],
      pointPlacement: 'on'
    }, {
      name: 'Degenerate Case',
      data: [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00],
      pointPlacement: 'on'
    }]
  });
});
```

I was wondering whether such features are not available for polar charts (I wasn't able to read anything like that in the manual) or how to do that, in case I am doing something wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `startOnTick: false` and `minPadding: <0-1>` to make some space below zero, some examples:

- minPadding: 0.1 => http://jsfiddle.net/6EGeE/1/
- minPadding: 0.5 => http://jsfiddle.net/6EGeE/4/

Comment: This is even better! Thanks @Paweł !

Answer (score 0):

Is the `min` yAxis property what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/6EGeE/

```
yAxis: {
  gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
  lineWidth: 0,
  min: -1
},
```

Comment: Hi @rafael ! Thanks for the reply... Believe me or not, I tried `min` and it wasn't working in my full project... I wonder whether it clashes against something else... I'll give it another try and I'll also try to play with ticks because I think a `min: -0.05` is more than enough (in the above example, it is automatically changed in `-0.5` as the tick interval is `0.5`). Anyway, many thanks!

Comment: I tried with `tickInterval: 0.05,` and now the negative part is as small as I want, but I get too many ticks in the range [0.0, 1.0]... do you know if there is a way to hide most of them?

Comment: Can't you wipe them out of your data before sending to the chart?